# Android - <Include/> Data Binding

Tags: android, xml, onclicklistener, android-databinding

I've reading some examples and Android documentation, but my implementation isn't working

I've my activity and my viewmodel.

**Activity Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

    <data>
        <variable
            name="viewmodel"
            type="package.to.viewmodel"/>
    </data>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

        <include
            app:viewmodel="@{viewmodel}"/>

        <!-- More Code -->

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</layout>
```

**Include Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewmodel"
            type="package.to.viewmodel"/>
    </data>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <!-- More Code -->

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:onClick="@{viewmodel.newButtonClickListener}"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

**ViewModel Code**

```
public class MainViewModelImpl implements MainViewModel {

    private View.OnClickListener newButtonClickListener;
    private View.OnClickListener newEventButtonClickListener;
    private View.OnClickListener newAssignmentButtonClickListener;
    private View.OnClickListener newContactButtonClickListener;
    private View.OnClickListener newChatButtonClickListener;

    //All the getters for the Listeners
}
```

So the code builds and runs without errors, but when I tap the button nothing happens, even though my listeners are correctly implemented.

Does anyone has an idea on why are the listeners not been triggered?

**Update**
When I was debugging the application, I realize that the viewmodels in the include layout are null, even after the binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, I was doing the binding before inflating the view. So now it works.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

When you set the viewModel variable in the include you should use `bind:viewmodel` instead of `app:viewmodel`.

An example is available [in the official documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html) or [in the demo project](https://github.com/fabioCollini/DataBindingInAction) of my data binding talk.

Comment: Haha sorry, that is relative to the name of the namespace you use for `.../res-auto` I used app